# How to add basic logic in AWS S3 or cloudfront?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Let's say I have two files: one for safari and one for Firefox.

I want to check User-Agent and return file based on the User-Agent.

How do I do this without adding external server?

Comment: what kind of file?

Comment: Two CSS files for example. Or two images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this without adding an extra server.

S3 supports static content.  It does not¹ vary its response based on request headers.

CloudFront relies on the origin server if content needs to vary based on request headers.  Note that by default, CloudFront doesn't forward most headers to the origin, but this can be changed in the cache behavior configuration.  If you forward the `User-Agent` header to the origin, your cache hit rate drops dramatically, since CloudFront has no choice but to assume any and every change in the user agent string could trigger a change in the response, so an object in the cache that was requested by a specific user agent string will only be served to a future browser with an identical user agent string.  It will cache each different copy, but this still hurts your hit rate.  If you only want to know the general type of browser, CloudFront can inject special headers to tell the origin whether the user agent is desktop, smart-tv, mobile, or tablet, without actually forwarding the user agent string and causing the same negative impact on the cache hit ratio.

So CloudFront *will correctly cache* the appropriate version of a page for each unique user agent... but the origin server must implement the actual content selection logic.  And when the origin is S3, that isn't supported -- unless you have a server between CloudFront and S3.  This is a perfectly valid configuration -- I have such a setup, with a server that rewrites the request path received from CloudFront before sending the request to S3, then returns the content from S3 back to CloudFront, which returns the content to the browser.

AWS Lambda would be a potential candidate for an application like this, acting as the necessary server (a serverless server, if you will) between CloudFront and S3... but it does not yet suport binary data, so for anything other than text, that isn't an option, either.

---

¹At least, not in any sense that is relevant, here.  Exceptions exist for CORS and when access is granted or denied based on a limited subset of request headers.

Comment: So, what would be better? Rewrite path on ec2 or pull data from S3 and send to cloudfront from ec2? If so, how will cloudfront cache the data? Since the response will be different based on User-Agent even though same URL?

Comment: If you configure CloudFront to forward the `User-Agent` header to the origin, it automatically caches each different version of the page and will serve it back to any future requester with exactly the same user agent string. "Which is better?" Those are just two ways of saying the same thing.  When I say "rewrite the path," I don't mean redirect the browser. I just mean change the path from what the browser requested so that you fetch the actual object you want to serve from S3, in cases where that's different than what the browser requested, e.g. change `/index.html` to `/index.firefox.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this with [Lambda@Edge](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html). Here is [an official example](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/networking-and-content-delivery/dynamically-route-viewer-requests-to-any-origin-using-lambdaedge/) that does something similar to what you are wanting to do.